# Смена ночной/светлой темы на разных страницах React приложения

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hook

Есть код, который переключает id {theme} в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, но он делает это в пределах одной страницы. Мне нужно решение как сделать так, чтобы id переключался на разных страницах в моём react приложении (Home, Gallery,News,Start)

## settings.js

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/settings.css';
import { createContext } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext(null)


function Settings() {
   
   
const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark')

const toggleTheme = () =>{

   setTheme((curr)=>(curr==="light"? "dark": "light"));
}

    return(

      
 

 <div className="settings__wrapper" >

<h2>НАСТРОЙКИ</h2>    





<div className="settings__buttons">




<ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>

<div  className="setting__button" id={theme}>

   <p className="setting__text"></p> 
<label onChange={toggleTheme} checked={theme==="dark"} class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
</ThemeContext.Provider>
</div>
 </div>
 
    )
    
}




export default Settings;
```

## App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react";

import Home from './components/home';

import Gallery from './components/gallery';


import News from './components/news';


import Start from './components/start'

import Settings from './components/settings'


import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes,Route, } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from './components/navigation';




function App() {
  return (


  

 <BrowserRouter>

<Navigation></Navigation>

    <Routes>

     
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/> 

    <Route path="/gallery" element={<Gallery />}/> 


    <Route path="/news" element={<News/>}/> 

    <Route path="/start" element={<Start/>}/> 



    <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings/>}/> 


    </Routes>
   
    
    
   
    </BrowserRouter>




    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: попробуйте хранить состояние theme не в useState
а в reduce или recoil

Comment: Можно сохранять в [localSorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) и в каждой компоненте читать отуда значение (можете написать собственный хук например `useTheme` и вызывать в каждой компоненте). Это поможет пользователю после обновления страницы сохранить значение темы, чтобы вручную каждый раз не переключать

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто стоит перенести провайдер темы `ThemeContext.Provider` в `App.js`

```js
<ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    ...
  </BrowserRouter>
</ThemeContext.Provider>
```

Comment: К сожалению ваше решение не подходит,  при попытке вставить id={theme} в любой элемент на разных страницах react его не может определить и выдаёт : Uncaught ReferenceError: theme is not defined

Comment: @Tail_Wind Вам так же необходимо перенести стейт theme и метод toggleTheme в компонент App. Ну и для удобства можете перенести создание контекста в файл App.js

Comment: Именно всё, что вы написали я как раз таки и делал, в этом и заключается вся проблема.

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста код, который у вас получился